# How to decode the percentile encoded byte[]

Tags: java, python, rest, post, url-encoding

I am sending a byte stream to the the rest service using the post method as follows :

```
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
h.add_credentials("admin","admin")

data = urllib.urlencode({"packet":str(pack)})
resp, content = h.request(url, "POST", data)
```

the post call results to encode the byte stream with the `%` (`data` is encoded). Now I want to retrieve back the original byte stream. I tried in following manner at the rest service side (java) but I am not able to retrieve the original byte stream.

```
String pack_decode = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(packet, "UTF-8");
// I am expecting decoded byte stream (free from `%` encoding) but I am getting the same encoded string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post whole source code? It seems this should work, at least next is working fine on my side:

Client (Python):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import httplib2
import urllib

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test'
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
pack = 'Источники в Кремле: вердикт Гааги по ЮКОСу не важен, потому что грядет война в Европе'
data = urllib.urlencode({"packet":str(pack)})
resp, content = h.request(url, "POST", data)
```

Server (Java):

```
package com.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/test", new Handler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    }

    static class Handler implements HttpHandler {
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

            InputStreamReader isr =  new InputStreamReader(t.getRequestBody(),"utf-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            int b;
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(512);
            while ((b = br.read()) != -1) {
                buf.append((char) b);
            }

            br.close();
            isr.close();

            System.out.println("Encoded msg: \n" + buf); 

            String pack_decode = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(buf.toString(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Decoded msg: " + pack_decode); 

        }
    }

}
```

Output on Server side:

Encoded:

packet=%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%3A+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82+%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%AE%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%A1%D1%83+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%2C+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B2+%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5

Decoded:

packet=Источники в Кремле: вердикт Гааги по ЮКОСу не важен, потому что грядет война в Европе